# panel.abline on "lattice plot in Shiny" got error

Tags: r, shiny, annotations, panel, lattice

I don't know very well about **lattice** but I know here the *openair::timePlot* function call *lattice.xyplot* to plot time series of pollutant concentrations .
('timePlot','selectByDate' functions and dataset called 'mydata' are part of Openair package

I want to add ref line to each panel accordingly.
Ref line Y s are calculated and store in **ref**

```
library(openair)
df <- selectByDate(mydata, year = 2003, month = 3)
ref <- c(10, 2, 30)
timePlot(df, pollutant = c("so2", "co","pm25"),
         y.relation = "free",
         ref.y = list(h = ref, lty=5, col="blue"))
```

[image]

Biult-in ref.y add all 3 refline to each panel which is not what I want.

So I try this which is works locally.

```
timePlot(df, pollutant = c("so2", "co","pm25"),
         y.relation = "free")
trellis.last.object() +
    layer(panel.abline(h = ref[1], lty = 5,col="red"), rows = 1) +
    layer(panel.abline(h = ref[2], lty = 5, col="blue"), rows = 2)
```

[image]

But when I use it on a simple Shiny app, I got errors.

Here is an app.R working but can reproduce one error.

```
library(openair)
library(shiny)
library(latticeExtra)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotOutput("timePlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$timePlot <- renderPlot({
        df <- selectByDate(mydata, year = 2003, month = 3)
        timePlot(df, pollutant = c("so2", "co","pm25"),              
                y.relation = "free")
        ref <- c(15, 1, 40)
        trellis.last.object() +
            layer(panel.abline(h = 15, lty = 5), rows = 1) +
            layer(panel.abline(h = ref[2], lty = 5), rows = 2) 
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It seems that the **h** only takes numberic value directly. When I assign value from other varible,like ref, it says "object not found", or "object type closure is not subsettable"/double" .
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any clues?  Thanks!!

ps: tried creating my panel function. but it breaks timePlot output I want.

Comment: You are more likely to receive an answer if you provide a sample of your data `mydata`, also share the "simple" shiny app.

Comment: Hi! "mydata" is not my data, it is the dataset provided by the "Openair" package.  My shiny app is just to get data from our database and then show this plot.  I'll remove db connection part and add the to my post.